# PHP safe $_GET or not

Tags: php, get

We have url:

```
http://site.com/index.php?action=show
```

`$_GET['action']` is used in templates to check value of `?action=`:

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case = "show" {
        $match_show = true;
    }
}
```

and in other place:

```
echo $_GET['action'];
```

Is it absolutely safe to use this constructions?

How to make them safe?

Thanks.

Comment: Never directly echo data send from the clouds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The switch thing is okay, because you are comparing against a hard-coded value (however, it's `case "show":` btw).

As @Bruce mentions in the comments, you should add a `default:` case as well to catch values that are not on the list, or empty values:

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {

    case "show":
        $match_show = true;
        break;

    default: 
        // value is not on the list. React accordingly.
        echo "Unknown value for 'action'". 

}
```

The second thing is potentially dangerous, as it would be possible to inject HTML and more importantly, JavaScript into the document body. You should apply a `htmlspecialchars()` on the variable before echoing it.

Comment: Didn't notice he was using switch to filter stuff + 1

Comment: I tend to go further and validate `$_GET['action']` against a list of expected actions, failing out if it's not one of them

Comment: @Michael good point. @Ignatz be sure to have a `default:` case in your switch.

Comment: The `switch` will throw an error (if enabled) if `'action'` does not exist. Checking the input against a fixed set is good, but you should also check that the parameter is passed at all in addition to adding a `default` case.

Comment: `$_GET['action']` will also fail if `'action'` does not exist. This may display errors (or stop execution), depending how PHP is configured.

Answer (score 9):

The `$_GET` superglobal is not safe by default as it may contain special or encoded characters and other undesirable text sequences.

You can use the built in PHP function [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to sanitize the string according to several standard filters (see the [list of filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) for an idea of what is possible).

**Example:**

```
if (!($action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))) {
    $action = 'some-default'; 
}
```

*Advantages:*

Relies on built-in sanitize filtering, which ensures:

- security fixes are available as PHP is patched
- consistent/standard filtering
- solid filter implementation (in terms of performance and security)
- also provides a clear default case

*Disadvantages:*

- syntax is a bit of a bear to remember
- cannot use `filter_input` if you modify the superglobal `$_GET` (which you probably shouldn't do anyway).

**Side note**

You could also check that the field was one of a set using [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array), which is a more dynamic method of checking if you have one of a set.

```
$search = in_array($search, array('show', 'hide')) ? $search : 'some-default';
```

The dynamic approach allows you to either execute or look up the target action safely, while storing the set of potential choices in a data structure versus static code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as mentioned, you must validate the value of any `$_GET` variable before using it blindly. But...

You should also be checking that it even exists before using it. Depending on how you have error_reporting() set on your server, if you try to use `$_GET['action']` and `?action=something` has not been specified in the URL then you'll get an **E_NOTICE - Undefined index : action**, which will either pollute your error logs or worse, appear in the browser.

```
$urlAction = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null;

if (isset($urlAction)) {
  // Rest of validation...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP `$_GET` by itself is insecure, it can be exploited in several areas, for a good reading and examples I recommend you to read this article

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-security-blunders

Comment: Bullshit. $_GET is not "insecure by itself". It contains data that could be manipulated, but as long as that data is not used stupidly, that is *not* a security risk.

Comment: @Flakron the link you post to is a good resource nevertheless, and those blunders tend to happen often.

Comment: You should clarify that it's not $_GET that is insecure, but the values in $_GET that you can't rely on being valid.

Comment: @Pekka That's somewhat debatable; most of the "PHP blunders" seem to be standard web security problems that have nothing to do with PHP

Comment: @Michael definitely. The blunders are not specific to PHP (although other platforms do a better job of filtering out some attacks). But the article is worth a read for every PHP newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when i have alot of begginers create plugins or moduldes for a site i use something like...

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
  if(functions_exists('clean_get_'.$key)) {
    $_GET[$key]=call_user_func('clean_get_'.$key,$value);
  } else {
    unset($_GET[$key];
  }
}
```

... and all the get and post values are 'magically' cleaned or removed so i don't need to worry about someone elses sql-injectable plugin.

Or, if you are a fan of lazy-loading ...

```
   foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
      if(is_file('clean_get_'.$key.'.php')) {
        include_once('clean_get_'.$key.'.php');
        if(functions_exists('clean_get_'.$key)) {
          $_GET[$key]=call_user_func('clean_get_'.$key,$value); 
        } else {
          unset($_GET[$key]);
        }
      } else {
        unset($_GET[$key];
      }
    }
```

ps. code was written here directly, mistakes are probable!

Answer (score 1):

To replace empty (not set) values with default ones try this:

```
 $variable = isset($_GET['get_variable']) ? $_GET['get_variable'] : 'some-default';
```