# Check that no variables have been passed

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, include, if-statement

I have one file index.php, I am trying to include 
splash.php when no variable is passed 
and 
display.php when any variable is passed.

This is what i have so far but i want to make it universal for all variables instead of just "query".

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['query']))
{
include("splash.php");
}
else {
include("display.php");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if $_GET is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408616/how-to-check-if-get-is-empty)

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of the abovementioned question because most solutions there apply to `$_REQUEST` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (count($_REQUEST) == 0) {
   include("splash.php"); 
} else { 
   include("display.php"); 
}
```

though you're better checking $_POST or $_GET (as appropriate) rather than the looser $_REQUEST

Comment: Note that depending on your php.ini cookies might be included in the `$_REQUEST` array too. So checking if `count()` is zero might fail when you have a session running (or set any other cookies). `$_POST` and `$_GET` clearly are better candidates.

Comment: @svens - hence my additional comment about $_GET and $_POST