# PHP - check to see if any GET data is set

Tags: php, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if $_GET is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408616/how-to-check-if-get-is-empty)

I'm trying to check for the condition that there is any `$_GET` data in my urls `?var=foo&biz=bang`, and the `if` statement I'm currently using to do this is `isset($_GET) //Do something`, but it's return truey even though there isn't even any `?` or `&` anywhere in my URL. I'm assuming that the `$_GET` variable is always set, so how do I check for this?

[Duplicate of "How to check if $_GET is empty?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408616/how-to-check-if-get-is-empty?rq=1)

Comment: I just realized my question is a duplicate, but I can't find the original in the flagging options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $_GET is *always* **set** in php (when run in a webserver), what you really want to know is "is anything in there?"

You want to use:

```
if ($_GET) {
}
```

This works because $_GET is an array, and an empty array will be evaluated `false`, while a populated array is `true`.

---

*UPDATE*

I no longer use the above method, since it has really negative effects on testability and CLI-run commands (`phpunit`, `artisan`).

I now always check `isset()` on the `$_GET` array. I also usually assign to an array inside the `if` - php evaluates these expressions to the value of the assigned variable.

If your framework has a "safe array access" function, you should always use it. If you framework has a "safe GET function" that's even better.
If you aren't using a framework, or your framework does not include these helper functions, you should write them for yourself.

```
// example with "safe array access"
if (isset($_GET) && $value = safe_array($_GET, 'key')) {
    // do something with $value
}

// example with "safe GET function"
if ($value = safe_input_get('key')) {
    // do something with $value
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Are you sure empty arrays return false?

Comment: Whoops! My bad. I left a `!` in there. Your code definitely works :P

Comment: Upvoted and commented so hopefully the top (wrong) answer isn't accepted

Comment: @Rambo brings up a good point: $_GET will not be set if you are running from the CLI or other non-web method. This is a real problem for testability, so you should wrap your calls to $_GET in a function to handle exceptions (missing keys) and let you inject values when urls are unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!empty($_GET))
{
    // do something
}
```

That should let you know if the get array is populated

Comment: $_GET is always set in a web enviornment, which makes !empty slightly redundant.

Comment: Rambo is correct and this answer is NOT correct..  $_GET is often set without any $_GET string being passed in the uri

Answer (score 0):

using `empty()` could possibly be problematic since it will return `true` for 0, 0.00, false, and others (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Possible workarounds:

```
<?php
function is_blank($value) {
    return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
}
if (!is_blank($_GET)){
   ... do your thing ...
}

?>
```

or check for a specific post value `isset($_POST['value'])`

Comment: $_GET will never have a value or `0` or `0.00` unless userland code has mucked with it. Some of the entries in the array may have those values, but that is irrelevant to whether or not $_GET converts to boolean true or false. An array coerces to false only when it has no array keys.

Comment: couldn't $_GET be false though?

Comment: No. It could be completely undefined(which is null, which in turn then coerces to false) if you're running php in a non web environment, for example, via the command line. Or, if the php config has been set to not populate that superglobal(extremely uncommon in a web environment), it again will be undefined. I'm of the opinion that extenuating circumstances like these should throw errors/notices, because they truely are error conditions which the code has not anticipated and isnt programmed to handle.