# Show an undefined $_GET value as defined in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

This is my controller,

```
/**
 * @Route("/products")
 * @Template()
 */
public function productsAction() {
    if (isset($_GET)) {
            echo 'Category set';
            exit();
    }else{
            echo 'Category not set';
            exit();
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get,

> Category set

http://localhost:8000/products by add this URL.
It would be great help someone can look into it.

Comment: `$_GET` = `array()` != `unset`. Even when you don't have any keys, it's still an empty array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if $\_GET is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408616/how-to-check-if-get-is-empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to directly access the super-global `$_GET` if you are using the symfony framework for routing and the like.

If you are trying to do something when a category is present, instead, pass the category as a dynamic variable to the route as the 2nd argument. The first will be the function. Then $category will be available to you in the function.

```
/**
* @Route("/products/{category}")
* @Template()
*/
public function productsAction($category) {
    //$category is set so do something
    echo 'Category '. $category .' is set.';
}
```

Comment: just a sidenote, @Template() should not be used as it has overhead issues, not recommended by symfony docs

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Ohgodwhy also do not use `exit` inside symfony.

Comment: I don't believe that I've used `exit` inside of symfony.

Comment: I was referring to the question itself