# Is it safe to use the $_GET variable on a website

Tags: php, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP safe $_GET or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388983/php-safe-get-or-not)

So I'm going to build a dynamic website that loads content from a db. Of course I will sanitize the data before inserts and such, but I need to `mod_rewrite` the URLs, so I'm thinking I have to use the `$_GET` variable. Is this safe to use on modern sites?

Comment: everything is safe if used properly.

Comment: Querystrings are still used today.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I was second guessing myself!

Comment: There's nothing inherently *unsafe* about any user supplied values. It depends on what you *do* with them that makes them unsafe.

Comment: Does look like a possible duplicate as Thilo mentions.  You can use $_GET, just make sure you sanitize to avoid HTML injections

Comment: What are you going to use instead of GET and POST? Cookies?!

Comment: also, remember to use prepared statements when accessing your db.

Comment: you'd better explained what's behind "Of course I will sanitize the data". Because most of time such ideas of "sanitizing everything" turns out to be wrong, data-breaking and unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you sanitize your data there is no difference between using `$_GET`, `$_POST` or reading from a file.

It's not where the data is from that you should worry about, but the data itself and its use case.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong using `$_GET`/`$_POST`, it's just santizing and validating data that people forget.
But that can be said about any external data :)

Comment: What's santizing and validating data that people forget?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to send sensitive information such as your username or password, don't use `GET`.  In any other case you can use `GET` but check all data from `$_GET` and `$_POST` if you use `POST`.

Comment: You have to use POST when you are modifying data on the server side